# Metadata object handling in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I need to develop a custom form generator using Laravel.

That means there will be a GUI to select and customise the forms like `Registration Form` or `Booking Form`.User should be able to add/edit/delete different form controls, define it as mandatory, etc.

Here I am little confused to handle this in back-end. What is the better way to achieve this?

Or how can I implement a database architecture to use some metadata table which can be used to handle multiple items like `Wordpress` and is there any built-in Laravel functionalities to handle these meta objects?

And how the `insert/update/delete` handled in this metadata approach?

Here an insert should have only one row in the meta table. Suppose at the time of user registration, without saving the `firstname` and `lastname` in separate rows in the meta table, it should use some objects like this in a single row.

```
a:3:{s:9:"firstname";s:10:"irshad.far";s:8:"lastname";s:0:"";s:5:"_meta";a:7:{s:2:"ip";s:10:"14.99.80.3";s:9:"confirmip";s:10:"14.99.80.3";s:11:"confirmtime";d:1407932201;s:8:"signupip";s:10:"14.99.80.3";s:10:"signuptime";d:1407932201;s:4:"lang";s:2:"en";s:4:"form";s:7:"unknown";}}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Handling a table of meta data is fairly straight forward using Laravel's Eloquent relations. Let's say you have a users table in your database that contains:

```
id    email    password    created_at    updated_at    deleted_at
```

If you want to keep it simple and not add all sorts of extra data to your users table you could create a **`meta`** table and then a link table **`user_meta`** to relate the two.

But what if you also have a **`posts`** table (as with Wordpress) and your posts also need meta data? Instead of also creating a **`posts_meta`** table to link your posts to their meta, we can use Laravels Eloquent relations and create some [Polymorphic Relations](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations).

### The Database

Here's our setup, along with our **`users`** table (above) we have a **`posts`** table which has the fields:

```
id    title    content    created_at    updated_at    deleted_at
```

We also have our **`meta`** table that follows the guidelines for a polymorphic relation:

```
id      name        value         metable_id      metable_type
//int   meta key    meta value    post/user id    resource ie post/user
```

Using this we could add meta for a post or user to our meta table like this:

```
id    name       value      metable_id    metable_type
------------------------------------------------------
1     nickname   Steve      1             User
2     author     Steve O    1             Post
```

All we need to do to grab this info from the database is define the relations in our respective models.

### The Models

So now we have our DB ready we need to setup our models (one model for User, one for Post and one for Meta) with our polymorphic relationship. Our `User` and `Post` models are both going to use the same function to relate to our `Meta` model:

```
User.php
========================================

class User extends Eloquent {
    public function meta()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('Meta', 'metable');
    }
}


Post.php
========================================

class Post extends Eloquent {
    public function meta()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('Meta', 'metable');
    }
}
```

Now we define the inverse of those relations in our meta model:

```
Meta.php
========================================

class Meta extends Eloquent {
    public function metable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

That's it!

### Getting the data

Now all you need to do to get at the meta data for a user or post is:

```
// Load in a post with an id of 1 and get all it's related meta
$post = Post::find(1);
$meta = $post->meta;
```

If we were to return the meta object we might see something like:

```
[{"id":2,"metable_id":1,"metable_type":"Post","name":"author","value":"Steve O"}]
```

### Onwards!

From here you can create helper functions like this one that checks if the meta you're after exists in the results:

```
public function hasMeta($key)
{
    $meta = $this->meta;

    foreach ($meta as $item):
        if( $item->name == $key ) return true;
    endforeach;

    return false;
}

// Use it like:
if($post->hasMeta('author')){
    // Display author
}
```

Read more about Laravels Eloquent relationships in the docs here: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-relationships

Comment: Thanks, I will try this next day and update you.

Comment: I think this one is simple and straight forward way. I am expecting little advanced way. When I checked some wordpress plugin it stores entire data related to an entity in a single row like this ``a:3:{s:9:"firstname";s:10:"irshad.far";s:8:"lastname";s:0:"";s:5:"_meta";a:7:{s:2:"ip";s:10:"14.99.80.3";s:9:"confirmip";s:10:"14.99.80.3";s:11:"confirmtime";d:1407932201;s:8:"signupip";s:10:"14.99.80.3";s:10:"signuptime";d:1407932201;s:4:"lang";s:2:"en";s:4:"form";s:7:"unknown";}}``. And also they are extracting each item like ``firstname`` and ``lastname`` from this object.

Comment: Yeah this is really the base of your meta setup. You can get as complicated as you want with the data you store in your meta table. You may want to `json_encode()` a bunch of vars in the `value` field like the wordpress setup. It's also worth noting that all your meta data in the example is attached to it's relevant `post`/`user` object, so you can still get at your main values very easily.

Comment: How we can handle search in the object which contains a bunch of data like above?

Comment: You'll want to perfom a custom query of your database most likely. You could loop through a results set but if you have a large set with a lot of meta data that's going to give you performance issues. Best results are going to be from an optimised custom DB query.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I once did something similar, my approach was to build a mini DB engine where forms are like tables and data is rows:

A form which describes the structure and design of a form:

```
Form {
    id,
    title,
    layout,
    ...
}
```

Fields of the form with types and validation rules

```
Field {
    formId,
    name,
    type (String, Date, Image, Integer, Double, List, ...),
    pattern (Regex validation maybe),
    ...
}
```

Inserted data in a form is a row belonging to that form

```
Row {
    id,
    formId,
}
```

Each row is a group of entries to fields of the corresponding form that can be validated following the predefined rules.

```
Entry {
    rowId,
    fieldId,
    value
}
```

- Type and rules can be regrouped in another object so you can have dynamic types that you can manage.
- Lists can have another object that stores choices and type of list (multi-select, mono-select)

Answer (score 0):

Metadataobjects itself would be saved in one table. But performance-wise I think those object should their own data tables.

Approach 1)

These types of forms needs to be predefined and linked to a specific controller. This must be either so that there is only one controller for each type of form like Registeration, and only one user defined metadataobject can be in use at either time. This controller's table parameter would be set to point to a database table created specifically for that metadataobject (or perhaps same table could be migrated according to metadata but then that table should be empty).

Or 2) every metadataobject should have it's own controller created which points to the object's data table.

In each approach routes needs to be created to point to the one controller of each type at use in each time.

One dilemma is how to manage revisions of those objects. Perhaps each object might have a running number postfix, and have their own controllers and data tables created (then it might be easier to migrate even populated tables [then user would be notified on front-end if his action would result in data loss, like for example with deleting a form data field]).

Another part of this project is to create an intelligent generator engine for assembling the HTML, CSS, and JS code according to a metadataobject. The generated code can be saved to reside in the same table as the objects themselves, and when used should be cached in the backend for rendering views.

Such metadataobject must itself have a clever format, so that it composes of predefined pieces of settings which will be converted to functionality by the form generator code.